# MVC Chart Helper - Passing data from controller to view

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, mschart

In my MVC application, I am using a chart inside of a razor view. If the chart is placed in `Details.cshtml`, then the entire screen is the chart so it needs to be a partial. The initial data is being calculated in the `Details()` method of the controller and I am passing it to the view in a `ViewBag`. I am then passing the `ViewBag` to the controller for the `Chart()` method.

I am unable to render the chart by passing the data with the `ViewBag`. The error is `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeExcption: Data points insertion error Number of X values is less than Y values`, which is telling me that it is not reading the `ViewBag.m`.

I have checked to see if the `ViewBag.months` is making it to the `Chart()` method, and it is. So `ViewBag.m` should be making it to `Chart.cshtml`, but I cannot tell since I was unable to even produce any kind of text rendering with the partial.

controller...

```cs
public ActionResult Details()
{
  ...
  ViewBag.months = new string[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May" };
  return View(item);
}

 public ActionResult Chart(string[] months)
 {
   ViewBag.m = months;
   return View();
 }
```

Details.cshtml

```cs
...
@RenderChart()

@helper RenderChart()
{
  <div id="chart-content" style="margin-top: 15px">
  <img src="@Url.Action("Chart", "Sales", new { months = ViewBag.months })" />
  </div>
}
...
```

Chart.cshtml

```cs
@{
  var myChart = new Chart(width: 300, height: 200)
    .AddTitle("Sales")
    .AddSeries(
        name: "Months",
        chartType: "Line",
        xValue: ViewBag.m,
        yValues: new[] { "2", "6", "4", "5", "3" })
    .Write();
}
```

How can the chart access the data in the partial view?

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `ViewBag.months` is a collection, and you cannot pass a collection using `new { months = ViewBag.months }` in your `Url.Action` (if you look at the url it generates it would be something like `../Sales/Chart/System.Collections.Generic.List'[string]`

Comment: Ok, thanks for leading me to understand that aspect. Is there a better way for me to accomplish passing data through the partial yet being generated in the Details method?

Comment: Start by getting rid of that awful `@helper` (one of the worst features of mvc and fortunately been dropped in core-mvc). You could use `@Html.Partial()` or `@Html.Action()` (to call a `[ChildActionOnly]` that returns a partial), and pass the collection to the partial. But ideally you should also get rid of `ViewBag` and use a view model containing a `IEnumerable<string> Months` property for the collection.

Comment: In any case, `xValue: ViewBag.m,` will not work. You need to convert the collection to a javascript array first - i.e. `var months = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.m))` and then `xValue: months,`

Comment: Thanks guys... I will make some changes. It was hard to find any information about the usage of charts.